# Piping wget into tar using python

Tags: python, linux, pipe

Just starting out with python and linux, and wanted to make a simple script to pull a set of PDFs from a website, drop them into a tar file, and scp them to another machine. (in other words, grab a set of files in an automated way, package them, and send them to storage).

I can't get the data to pipe correctly. What would be helpful is to know whether this is just a bad approach to the problem, or where I'm just screwing up the syntax.

```
for x in range(1, 4):
 f = subprocess.Popen("wget", fullurl, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 g = subprocess.Popen("tar", "-rf", "file.tar"], stdin=f.stdout)
```

note - file.tar already exists, so new files should just be appended to it.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what's going wrong, and the error message and/or incorrect behavior you're getting?

Comment: The way you pass arguments to Popen is certainly syntactically screwed.

Comment: http://www.seanelavelle.com/2011/08/03/using-pythons-subprocess-module-to-run-piped-commands/

Comment: Why don't you use urllib? Also wget by default writes to a file, not stdout.